# Does the "Alternate Reality" Crisis require each player to destroy 12 cost worth of Heroes?

Tags: dc-comics-deck-building

The [*Crisis Expansion (Pack 1)*](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/155428/dc-comics-deck-building-game-crisis-expansion-pack) for the [*DC Comics Deck-Building Game*](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/125678/dc-comics-deck-building-game) introduced a new Crisis Mode, which allows for cooperative play and "Crisis Cards" that involve villains' plans. There has been one that has bothered me in particular, "Alternate Reality", which says the following:

> **Ongoing:** At the start of your turn, destroy all Heroes in your hand. Gain that many random Villains from the destroyed pile and put them into your hand.
>
> **To Beat:** Your team must destroy 12 cost worth of Heroes in their discard piles.

Does this mean that each player of the team must destroy 12 cost worth of Heroes in each of their discard piles? Or do they have to collectively have at least 12 cost worth of Heroes (say, 3 points in each of 4 discard piles)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is actually answered in the Specific Card Clarifications section of the Crisis rulebook:

> **Alternate Reality, Final Countdown:** To beat one of these Crisis cards, the team acts together and chooses which cards to destroy. The burden is on the collective team, so each player does not destroy their own set of cards to beat the Crisis. For Alternate Reality, you don't have to destroy exactly 12 cost worth of Heroes to beat it.

As it clearly says, "each player does not destroy their own set of cards" and it's up to the team to pick and choose which cards from which discard piles to destroy so that the total is 12 (or more) points of Heroes.